# How do I perform a kruskal wallis and then dunns test in r

Tags: r

DATA is of 8 locations, multiple replications of samples at each location. Data is non-parametric, hence Kruskal Wallis. Started this in excel as its where I understand most. However having done Dunn test between the first 2 locations, its clear that it will take a long time to carry out each test. I'm not great at R so if anyone could help that would be great.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you add a sample of your data to your question? You can paste the output of `dput(yourdataset)` (or  if the set is large use `dput(head(yourdataset))`. You may also try yourself and show it here (using a [tutorial](https://www.datanovia.com/en/lessons/kruskal-wallis-test-in-r/)). People appreciate it when askers show a little initiative. After all, SO is a we-help-you-when-your're-stuck site and not a we-do-all-the-work site.

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment Jan, ive added my data set and although ive attempted the code myself i've not yet been successful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your data set …

```r
dataset <- structure(list(location = c("hythe", "hythe", "hythe", "hythe", "hythe", "hythe", "wivenhoe sailing club", "wivenhoe sailing club", "wivenhoe sailing club", "wivenhoe sailing club", "wivenhoe sailing club", "wivenhoe sailing club", "seawall", "seawall", "seawall", "arlesford creek", "arlesford creek", "arlesford creek", "saltmarsh", "saltmarsh", "saltmarsh", "bateman tower", "bateman tower", "bateman tower", "hammerhead", "hammerhead", "hammerhead", "hammerhead pier", "hammerhead pier", "hammerhead pier"), dmsp.concentration.µmol.g...1..FW = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.181668036, 8.74281425, 16.59874901, 11.8695894, 13.08381347, 30.45514966, 16.9007997, 34.84822703, 16.99163987, 33.70192603, 17.47610675, 3.566103709, 3.489467239, 25.56108156, 41.89156166, 100.6923274, 7.237689965, 37.01883129, 68.91748911, 38.09262754, 35.60074182, 52.16561589, 38.04662926, 49.8158726, 64.07548762)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -30L))
```

you simply call the appropriate function. There are two ways of doing that.
First option is to provide a numeric vector and a category vector:

```r
kruskal.test(dataset$dmsp.concentration.µmol.g...1..FW, dataset$location)
#> 
#>  Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test
#> 
#> data:  dataset$dmsp.concentration.µmol.g...1..FW and dataset$location
#> Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 23.39, df = 7, p-value = 0.001457
```

Second option is the formula interface:

```r
kruskal.test(dmsp.concentration.µmol.g...1..FW ~ location, dataset)
#> 
#>  Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test
#> 
#> data:  dmsp.concentration.µmol.g...1..FW by location
#> Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 23.39, df = 7, p-value = 0.001457
```

I am not sure but I do not think basic R know the Dunns test. There are several packages with according functions. Here, I use the `FSA`. If you do not have it, use `install.packages("FSA")` to get it.

Once the package is installed, this should do the trick. You can use the same formula from your kruskal-wallis test.

```
library(FSA) # load library

# perform Dunn's Test with Bonferroni correction for p-values
dunnTest(dmsp.concentration.µmol.g...1..FW ~ location,
         data=dataset,
         method="bonferroni")
```

Comment: Can i just ask what the need for the P-value correction is?

Comment: A p-value correction is due when you [test multiple comparisons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonferroni_correction). The probability p(A ∪ B) > p(A) or p(B) alone. The more comparisons you make, the larger the chance of a false positive. That is what the p-value correction is for. If you have further questions about the statistics you could take a look at [Cross validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Is there a way to plot those comparisons that are significant?